# STL algorithm/functional

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to use the transform algorithm (or any other part of the STL that would do the job) to change a sequence of ints. If the current element is more than 5, keep it. Else use 5.

This does not compile :

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.push_back(6);
vec.push_back(2);
vec.push_back(9);
vec.push_back(4);
vec.push_back(7);

std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), std::bind1st(std::max<int>(), 5));
```

I don't have access to C++11.

Comment: You shouldn't call the `max` function when giving it to `std::bind1st`. You want to give it the function, not the result of calling it with no arguments.

Comment: @chris Ah, shame you deleted your old (correct) comment, I’m referring to it in my answer. ;-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph, Oh, shoot, I thought I was crazy, but I forgot it needs the type aliases. More modern tools do the same without imposing that, so I forgot.

Comment: @chris Yeah, the C++98 `bind*` functions were a complete train wreck. Well, hindsight is 20/20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this task the more appropriate algorithm is `std::replace_if` . For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>


int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> vec;

    vec.push_back( 6 );
    vec.push_back( 2 );
    vec.push_back( 9 );
    vec.push_back( 4 );
    vec.push_back( 7 );

    for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++ )
    {
        std::cout << vec[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::replace_if( vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                     std::bind2nd( std::less<int>(), 5 ), 5 );

    for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++ )
    {
        std::cout << vec[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
6 2 9 4 7 
6 5 9 5 7
```

Comment: This is very nice! Exactly what I was looking for, although I'm still curious to why @Sebastians solution didn't work. Thanks Vlad!

Answer (score 2):

You unfortunately cannot use `bind*` with function pointers directly. To work around this, you’d normally use `std::ptr_fun` but in your case that won’t work either<sup>1</sup>. So the way forward is to wrap `std::max` into a functor:

```
template <typename T>
struct max : std::binary_function<T, T, T> {
    T operator ()(T value, T min) const {
        return std::max(value, min);
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), std::bind2nd(max<int>(), 5));
```

---

<sup>1</sup> It appears as if `std::bind1st(std::ptr_fun(&std::max<int>), 5)` should work but unfortunately this template instantiation creates two identical `operator()` overloads, since `std::max` takes its arguments as `const`.

Comment: Why we need binary functor ?

Comment: @P0W Clamping is a general-purpose algorithm. It should be a *general* function, not one written bespoke for this call. Hence my `clamp_lower` is a general function, to be used with `std::bind2nd`, similar to OP’s usage. Your code is a completely acceptable ([curried](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)) alternative but it requires the use of a closure even when we wouldn’t require it.

Comment: *"you unfortunately cannot use bind with function pointers"* is false, this is what `std::ptr_fun` is for

Comment: @PiotrS. True, I completely forgot about that (same as chris in the comment below the question … funny). Write an answer, then I can delete mine.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, just update yours, since `std::max` still cannot be used here, even with ptr_fun.

Comment: @PiotrS. Fair enough. FWIW it took me a while to figure out why this won’t work here. Rewritten.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [std::replace_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) instead of transform. This allows you to use a predefined comparsion functor like `std::less` or `std::greater` instead of `std::max`:

```
std::replace_if(vec.begin(),vec.end(),std::bind2nd(std::less<int>(),5),5);
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/h8bF3t) is a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Why do the two existing answers replace the perfectly good `std::max` with identically implemented functions/functors with different names? `std::max` is perfectly fine; it's the way you use the old binders that's wrong.

You say you don't have C++11. Do you have Boost? Boost.Bind will do the job:

```
std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(),
               boost::bind(&std::max<int>, _1, 5));
```

I can't remember what namespace the placeholder is in.

If you can't use Boost either, you need to keep in mind that the old binders need special nested types from their bound functor argument, and function pointers don't have those, which is why the `ptr_fun` helper exists:

```
std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(),
               std::bind1st(std::ptr_fun(&std::max<int>), 5));
```

Comment: `std::ptr_fun` won't help. It overloads `operator()` in such a way that `std::max` makes it have two identical overloads. The code would also break when moved to C++11 since `std::max<int>` has two overloads.

Comment: According to C++11 Appendix D.8.2.1 (I don't have the C++98 standard around), `ptr_fun` (or rather `pointer_to_binary_function`, which it returns) doesn't overload `operator()` at all. Do you mean that the call to `ptr_fun` itself is ambiguous? If so, it's only because of the new `initializer_list` overloads, which are *also* C++11-only. My code should work fine in C++98.

Comment: I tried your solution and it did indeed give me a compile error. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: @SebastianRedlm Sorry, I meant `std::binder1st` with `operator()`. It overloads for `const T &` and `T &`, so when `T` is `const int &`, they come out identical.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know the old binders were *that* broken.